# Using linux "tee" command in bashrc

Tags: linux, shell, tee

How to use linux "tee" command in bashrc for automatic logging everything you write in shell and get on screen parallel to somefile ?

Comment: Can you explain your problem or requirement with more detail?

Comment: "write"? can you give an example?

Comment: come on man, show a simple session and its result in the logfile.

Comment: problem solved: "script mylog" works fine - thanks everybody for help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want to record your shell session in a file, the easiest way is:

```
script mylog
```

It just opens a new shell. When you want to stop session recording, just type `exit`. After that, your recorded session will be in `mylog` file.

---

Alternatively you can do:

```
$ tee > mylog
```

And on another window:

```
$ tail -f mylog
```

But this is probably not what you want.

Comment: thanks for reply but i haveto explain what i mean. I want to log everything i am doing in bash to file like a history:  command and linux answer, command and linux answer without typing : command tee -a logfile, command tee -a logfile,

Comment: i have just to make a tutorial how to install some envionment

Comment: problem solved:  "script mylog" works fine - thank You

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :)